# Custom setup creation in c#

Tags: c#, installation

can you please help me to find solution for my problem that i mentioned below?

Actually, I have created custom installer for my application. In which, i have included a form for asking install location. How to pass this location to the installer. I had set the value at context.paramenter["targetdir"]=text1.text. but installer is always uses the default location like c:\programefiles\manufacturename\productname. I like to ask this install location from user then pass it installer.

Any one can help me?

Comment: Give more details. What sort of installer are you using?

Comment: The setup creation projects comes with Visual studio .net 2008. It is MSI(i think..)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to spend some time learning then there is a free and highly customizable setup/installer creator tool available called Windows Installer XML (WIX) at http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a standard Visual Studio Deployment project, the project will already include a form asking for the install location and will install all files you put in the "Application Folder" of the File System panel to this folder. This folder path is available to scripts or conditions as the TARGETDIR property. This is all done automatically, if it's not working you have changed something.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. But, I like to ask you that is there any way to asking the install location through our form which i designed.

Comment: Since I don't have the form you are talking about, there is no possible way I could answer that question. You will have to show the form source code.